# Can not save event.target.id into global variable

Tags: javascript

Below is a simplified version of a code, which I am trying to make work for some hours now.

My aim is to get the id of the element, which a user clicks on, and pass the id value to a global variable **targetId**.

Unfortunately, although I manage to pass the id to a variable **targetId**, I can only access it within **returnId** function.
If I try to access *targetId* outside of the function - it returns no value.

Why is that?

Thanks in advance for help! :)

```
var targetId;

function returnId(e) {
    targetId = e.target.id; 
}

element.addEventListener('click', returnId, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an asynchronous call. You have to implement it differently.
This has been answered multiple times...

Duplicate of : [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)